# How can I create a crypto wallet and import the new custom ERC20 Token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, go-ethereum

How can I create a function which allows to import new custom ERC20 Token and Send & Receive function in my Crypto Wallet?
I'm using React Native? Any example codes or github repos will be helpful.

Desire solution: In my Crypto wallet, I would like to have a function like the MetaMask. User allows to add custom ERC20 Token with Send,Receive and Total Balance function. How could I achieve that in React Native app? Is there any open source libraries I can use?

Comment: Are you wanting to build a mobile wallet application?

Comment: @abcoathup - Yes. It is a mobile application using React Native.

Comment: @abcoathup are you talking about a mobile wallet that you can add new ERC20 tokens to? What about automatically adding the tokens based on a users address?

Comment: @abcoathup - Oh yea! I need that as well. What I want is really exactly the function in MetaMask. Which allow user to add new ERC20 token and auto interact with the corresponding user account.Do you think you can provide some information to me about that? Or, do you have any boilerplate code I can refer to?

Comment: Some mobile wallets that have some open source code and some have libraries, please check the licences.

+ Trust Wallet: https://github.com/trustwallet

+ Status.im: https://github.com/status-im

+ Balance.io: https://github.com/balance-io

+ Rainbow: https://github.com/rainbow-me/rainbow